# How do I have my bot take action against a member who has received a warning within a set amount of time of joining? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanna have my discord.py bot take action against new members who have been warned within a set amount of time of joining; for example: if a user joins and gets a warning within an hour of joining, they get kicked.

I don't need help with the kick command or the warn command (I already have those setup), I just need a way to 'monitor' the members for the first set amount of time (an hour, for example).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When warning a user, you could take a look at their join date with `member.joined_at` and check if it is less than 1 hour (or whatever time you want) ago: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=joined_at#discord.Member.joined_at

Comment: @moinierer3000 How would I go about checking whether or not the member joined less/over an hour ago?

Answer (score 1):

In your warn command, you just need to check if they joined within the last hour. You can get the `datetime` object of when they joined with `member.joined_at`.

For example:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

@commands.command()
async def warn(self, ctx: commands.Context, user: discord.Member, *, reason: str):
    # Check if they joined in the last hour
    if datetime.utcnow() - user.joined_at < timedelta(hours=1):
        return await user.kick()

    # Otherwise, warn as usual
    ...
```

When you subtract two `datetime` objects, you get a `timedelta` object which supports comparisons. Here, you can check the difference between the two `datetimes` and if it's less than an hour, you can go straight to kicking them.

If you're using the latest branch of `discord.py`, you'll need to use `discord.utils.utcnow()` instead of `datetime.utcnow()` since `datetime` objects are timezone aware in `discord.py 2.0`.

Comment: That helped immensely, thank you for your help! I honestly would love to upvote this answer; but I'm unfortunately new to Overflow and it won't let me - so pardon me for that.